# Как сделать вывод в виджет ScrolledText, а не в терминал IDE?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, scrolledtext, END

from miha import pars

def show_new_password():
    console.configure(state='normal')  # enable insert
    console.insert(END, pars() + '\n')
    console.yview(END)
    console.configure(state='disabled')  # disable editing

root = Tk()
root.title("WOW, PARSING!")
root.geometry('800x800')
root['bg'] = "grey"

button = tk.Button(root,
                   text="Quit",
                   fg='black',
                   bg='yellow',
                   command=quit).pack()
action = tk.Button(root,
                   text='!Find out your folders!',
                   fg='red',
                   bg='white',
                   command=pars).pack()
console = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root,
                                    state='disable').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: У вас в коде и так вывод идет в ScrolledText, никакого вывода в терминал я не вижу. В чем тогда проблема?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.insert(INSERT,"текст")
```